# Dynamic checkbox name to assign its value

Tags: javascript

what is wrong with this code I get an undefined error. my checkbox is not an array on front end it uses different names and I want user to select only one checkbox:

```
function select_item(index){
  var choice_options = [];
  choice_options['S'] = 'item_cb_S';
  choice_options['T'] = 'item_cb_T';
  choice_options['Z'] = 'item_cb_Z';
  choice_options['D'] = 'item_cb_D';
  choice_options['N'] = 'item_cb_N';


  for (i in choice_options) {
      var vl = choice_options[i];

      if(vl.substring(8) == index) {
           document.wizardform.choice_options[index].checked = true;    
           //alert("true");
      }
      else {
        document.wizardform.vl.checked = false; 
      }
  }
  return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not so pretty but you could use eval......

```
function select_item(index){
  var choice_options = [];
  choice_options['S'] = 'item_cb_S';
  choice_options['T'] = 'item_cb_T';
  choice_options['Z'] = 'item_cb_Z';
  choice_options['D'] = 'item_cb_D';
  choice_options['N'] = 'item_cb_N';


  for (i in choice_options) {
      var vl = choice_options[i];

      if(vl.substring(8) == index) {
           eval("document.wizardform." + choice_options[index] + ".checked = true;");
           //alert("true");
      }
      else {
        document.wizardform.vl.checked = false; 
      }
  }
  return true;
}
```